# Excluding blocks of same size at different locations of a vector using R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a long vector of dimension 1000.

```
x=rnorm(1000,10,1)
```

Also have another vector,

```
y<-c(1,7,10,16,29,50)
```

I want a vector obtained from "x", after excluding the blocks of length 4 at the locations indicated by the vector y.

For example, I want to have a vector from "x",  after deleting the (1-4)th component, (7-10)th component, (16-19)th component, (29-32)th, and (50-53) component of "x".

I am using `list`:

```
x1=list()
for (k in 1:(length(y)-1))
{
  x1[[k]]=x[-(y[k]:(y[k]+3)),]          
}
x2=as.data.frame(x1)
```

I am considering very long vectors (dim=100k), so the above code is not efficient. Could anyone suggest any better code for doing the above operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create one set of values to remove and only subset once:

```
x[-unlist(lapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n,n+3) ))]
```

Or even the below, which might be a fraction slower, but will save you a couple of characters of typing:

```
x[-c(sapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n,n+3) ))]
```

Answer (score 3):

This ought to be reasonably efficient. It adds the vector 0:3 to each of the items in `y` and removes the indexed values:

```
x[ - outer(y, 0:3, "+") ]
```

Benchmarks are close but I think my version wins for coding economy:

```
>  x <- rnorm(1e7)
> y=sample(1e7, 1e5)
> system.time( replicate(10, {z<- x[-outer(y, 0:3, "+")]}  ) )
   user  system elapsed 
  6.519   1.629   8.126 
> system.time( replicate(10, {z<- x[-unlist(lapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n,n+3) ))]}))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.959   1.041   8.970
```

This might be bit faster (and it's what `outer` uses):

```
system.time( replicate(10, {z<- x[-( rep(y, times=4) +rep(0:3, each=length(y) ) )]}))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.493   1.754   7.208
```

But Robinson is correct that the first rep() call is not needed.

Comment: Tricky - bring on the benchmarks! All options seem to be very fast except for ludicrously sized vectors.

Comment: @thelatemail Interesting: with `microbenchmark(c(sapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n,n+3) )), unlist(lapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n,n+3) )), outer(y, 0:3, "+") )` I get that the `unlist` solution is the fastest by a hair.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with `rep`, since addition cycles through the vector:

```
x[-(y + rep(0:3, each = length(y)))]
```

According to my benchmark this is the fastest of the solutions by about 7-fold:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(c(sapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n,n+3) )), unlist(lapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n,n+3) )), outer(y, 0:3, "+"), rep(0:3, each = length(y)) + y )

Unit: microseconds
                                             expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
      c(sapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n, n + 3))) 25.992 27.9270 34.74009 28.8890 30.1080 146.436   100   c
 unlist(lapply(y, function(n) seq.int(n, n + 3)))  7.506  8.7910  9.64311  9.4120  9.8325  28.643   100  b 
                               outer(y, 0:3, "+")  7.912  8.9105 11.34952  9.6955 10.6820  71.677   100  b 
                   rep(0:3, each = length(y)) + y  1.145  1.4770  1.72713  1.6285  1.8680   5.767   100 a
```

Comment: To be fair, all options complete 10M 'x' length, 10K 'y' removals in less than 0.15 seconds on average over here.

Comment: @thelatemail quite right, this is some serious premature optimization

Answer (score 1):

Looks like thelatemail beat me to it

```
x[-unlist(lapply(y,function(x){return(seq(x,x+3))}))]
```